# Setting timezone in Tornado

Tags: python, timezone, tornado

How do people handle timezones in Tornado so that users see time formatted relative to their timezone? I know there's locale.format_date which defaults to GMT, but how do I set the right timezone based on the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the timezone offset by JavaScript into cookies using JavaScript

```
var userDate = new Date();
var tzOffset = userDate.getTimezoneOffset();
// Now set the cookie
```

Comment: And how is it generally handled on the server side, do I need to manually update every timestamp with the tzoffset? Tornado must have something simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon my dimness but why do you mean to format the date based on the user in the context of Tornado? Tornado is a server. The user is a client.

Comment: For example if a user in EST creates a blog entry at 10PM, the creation timestamp should be displayed as 7PM to users to PST.

Comment: No, you create the timestamp with timezone information. That's a universal time. When you later display it to the user you'll need to know the users timezone offset to display it in his "locale". There, Javascript will have to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`format_date` accepts a `gmt_offset`. This is slightly better than modifying the date yourself, but doesn't really help with all the other timezone intricacies.

One approach you could take if your dates are always in the past is to use relative format for dates (e.g. 10 mins ago), which is the default for tornado's format_date. You can couple that with some javascript if you need to prevent the dates from going stale.

http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/locale.html#tornado.locale.Locale.format_date